# JavaFX image padding

Tags: java, css, javafx-8

Simply question (hopefully).
Is it possible to add padding to an ImageView using CSS in JavaFX? I've tried insets, padding etc without any luck.

Alternatively can the same effect be add the Text Object.
Have explored Google with little success, not a deal breaker just makes things a bit cleaner.

Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `-fx-padding` is a property of a [Region](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region).

An [`ImageView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) is not a Region, therefore, you cannot directly use padding on an ImageView.  You can however place the ImageView in a Region to provide a padded area around the ImageView.

Here is a sample which uses a StackPane (which is a style capable region).  The padding is specified in FXML, but would equally work with CSS.

[image: sample]

In the sample the green border around the image is a padding.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>

<StackPane id="StackPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" style="-fx-background-color: forestgreen;" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2">
  <children>
    <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
      <image>
        <Image url="http://www.corwellphotography.net/image/2223982.jpeg" />
      </image>
    </ImageView>
  </children>
  <padding>
    <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
  </padding>
</StackPane>
```

As a StackPane or Region can contain any kind of node, the technique works equally for any kind of node (not just ImageViews).